# reshape tensor between two layers

Tags: tensorflow, reshape, tensor

I have a neural network in which I built my own layer and it gives result with the shape  `A = [10, 5]`.

I want to feed the result to another layer which takes input with shape `B = [10, 9, 5]`.

The input `B` is based on the previous result `A`, for example, selecting 9 different rows from `A` for 10 times,making a new tensor with the shape `[10, 9, 5]`.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

for loop will do:

```
a = tf.constant([[1, 2, 7], [3, 4, 8], [5, 6, 9]])

tensor_list = []
pick_times = 3
for i in range(pick_times):
    pick_rows = [j  for j in range(pick_times) if i != j]
    tensor_list.append(tf.gather(a, pick_rows))

concated_tensor = tf.concat(tensor_list, 0)
result = tf.reshape(concated_tensor, [3, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Thanks! But actually I need to choose 9 different rows for ten times. For example, I choose all rows except the first row, then I choose all rows except the second row and so on and so forth for ten times to make the new matrix with shape [10,9,5]. Is there a way to do it automatically instead of doing it one by one and use concate in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Convert the tensor A (output of the layer) into a numpy array with:

```
a=sess.run(A.eval())
```

For the sake of the example I'll use:

```
a=np.random.uniform(0,5,[10])
```

Then:

```
#choose wich element will be left out
out = np.random.randint(5, size=[10])

#array of different output layers without one random element
b=[]
for i in range(10):
  b.append(np.delete(a,out[i]))

#Stack them all together
B = tf.stack(b[:])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you think having two sessions (one here, the other for training) would be a problem? Besides I guess this shouldn't affect the back propagation process since no weights are used here, right?

Comment: Even if weights (tf.variable) were used, they would have not been affected because you are in the feed forward process here and you are not changing the weights.